# Loading related primary keys without PrimaryKeyRelatedField loads too long

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, dynamic-rest

To load related primary keys with a serializer it is possible to:

- use `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)`
- not define a related Serializer

Why does it take more than 20 seconds to load 6 records if I don't define a related serializer?

AltSchool/dynamic-rest is used together with djangorestframework==3.7.7

Thanks for any conceptual explanation.

Comment: You can use `from django.db import connection` `len(connection.queries)` before and after call to that serializer, to see if you are doing extra queries

Comment: Try https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to debug how many and what queries are being executed.